# How to query reference ID in GraphQL one to one relationship?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I would like to make a query which I can query product by productTypeId
due `product` and `productType` has a one-to-one relationship. I can select all products or product by Id, but I can't select to the reference field.

How can I achieve this?

Schema

```
type Query {
    products:[Product] (work)
    productById(productId:Int):Product(work)
    productByTypeId(productTypeId:Int):Product(not work)
}

type Product{
    productId: ID!,
    productName: String,
    productCode:String,
    unitInStock: Float,
    unitPrice:Float,
    orderLevel:Int,
    discount: Float,
    imageUrl: String,
    backgroundImgUrl: String,
    productType: ProductType
    productCategory:Category
}

type ProductType{
    productTypeId:ID!
    productTypeName:String,
    imageUrl: String,
    backgroundImageUrl:String
}
type Category{
    categoryId:ID!
    categoryName:String,
    categoryCode:String,
    imageUrl: String,
    backgroundImageUrl:String
}
```

Controller

```java
@QueryMapping
public List<Product> productByTypeId(@Argument Integer productTypeId) {
    return productRepo.findByTypeId(productTypeId);
}
```

Repository

```java
Page<Product> findByTypeId(@Param("productTypeId") Integer productTypeId, Pageable pageable);
    @Query(value = "select p.* from pos_product p where product_type__id =:productTypeId", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not good to make a function for every field in the product,
you can make a ProductFilterDto and set inside all the fields that the product can be filtered with.

then in your repository you apply these filters and return the result
I am not familiar with java so I will provide you a pseudo code:

```
type ProductFilterDto{
    productId: ID,
    productName: String,
    productCode:String,
    unitPrice:Float,
    orderLevel:Int,
    productTypeId: ID
    productCategoryId:ID
}
```

then in your repo you can do :

```
Page<Product> findByTypeId(@Query("filter") ProductFilterDto filter, Pageable pageable)
//DO the required SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your schema is defined `Product` is m:1 with `ProductType`. In this case your `productByTypeId` query should return a list of products, not a single product.

Change

```
productByTypeId(productTypeId:Int):Product
```

to

```
productByTypeId(productTypeId:Int):[Product]
```